# mod redirect rule to redirect both www and non www domain to same domain's subpage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have couple of records set in my route 53
one of the record set for www.domain.com is mapped to elastic ip
secondly is for domain.com and its alias to www.domain.com

now am trying to redirect when the user hit www.domain.com or domain.com to www.domain.com/blog

so I added a mod rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/blog [R=301,L]
```

The redirect is only working for domain.com not for www.domain.com

I want to redirect the www.domain.com to www.domain.com/blog.
can someone please point me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/blog [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek Thank you , i tried this but it goes to a multiple re-direct issue.

Comment: Fixed by adding,
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^$ store [L]